# How to have a FOR Loop in CMD return only the child items

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, icacls

I'm trying to create a FOR Loop that will TAKEOWN only the child items of a folder (folders and files) and not the parent folder. Here's what I have so far, which will work but I don't want to take ownership of the Temp folder just the child items. Hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance.

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=*" %i IN ('DIR /AD /S /B "C:\*TEMP"') DO TAKEOWN /R /F "%i"

FOR /F "DELIMS=*" %i IN ('DIR /AD /S /B "C:\*TEMP"') DO ICACLS "%i" /GRANT USERNAME:(F) /T
```

Comment: Remove the `/AD`?

Comment: but that will return everything with the word temp in it instead of just the directories,,,  I'm trying to just take ownership of files & folders that are only within the temp folders.

Comment: So `cd` into the directory before running `takeown`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm trying to take ownership of all files & folders in all temp folders... there are a lot of temp folders I would have to cd into in order to do this, might as well just make a list and go to each one independently in the GUI to do it.

Comment: You can use `pushd %1` and `popd` **inside the `for` loop**. And you can put `takeown` and `icacls` inside the **same** `for` loop.